# Using command line git with a visual studio project

Tags: git, visual-studio

If I open a sln in Visual Studio, can I use command-line Git (in PowerShell) to do my version control?

What issues might there be from not using Visual Studio's integrated Git?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) It mostly _Just Works_.  I regularly mix and match Bitbucket tools, SourceTree, Tortoise Git and command line tools, and, oh yeah, VS's tools

Comment: I'd say there's going to be a lot of opinions on how to set this up, but check out Scott Hanselman's [posts](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/take-your-windows-terminal-and-powershell-to-the-next-level-with-terminal-icons) on Windows Terminal with posh-git and oh-my-posh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to do your version control without any issues. The integrated terminal is just an alternative which does exactly what command-line Git does.